# Connecting Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: networking

I'm looking to get a little help in configuring my Kubuntu Desktop. My goal is to have my Windows PC connect via Ethernet to the Kubuntu system via Remote desktop and then use kubuntu to browse the web. I have xrdp already installed but having issues with Ethernet portion

Answer (score 1):

Check the following things:

- Do you have a remote desktop client/server for Windows?
- If you aren't using a router/switch between the computers, ensure that `avahi` is installed on Kubuntu and `Bonjour` on the Windows PC. THis is fastest done by installing iTunes in windows.
- If you aren't using a router/switch between the computers, set the network mode in Kubuntu to `Link-Local only`

Using ZeroConf aka Avahi aka Bonjour, the hostnames of the computers would be `computername.local`